# swift ios when do I need to use mediaTypes kUTTypeImage

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a image picker in my app where you can select images from camera roll or take a new picture then upload the images to my backend server.

But looking around others code I see that some people use this: 
 **imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeImage as String]**

Why do you need to set mediaTypes to kUTTypeImage?

I have not used that in my code bellow but everything still works fine

I select images like this through a UIAlertController:

```
//Check if camera exist
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.Camera) {
            let cameraAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Take a photo", style: .Default) { (action) in
                self.imagePicker.sourceType = .Camera
                self.imagePicked = 1
                self.presentViewController(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }

            alertController.addAction(cameraAction)
        }

        //Check if photo lib exist
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.PhotoLibrary) {
            let photosLibraryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Pick image", style: .Default) { (action) in
                self.imagePicker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
                self.imagePicked = 1
                self.presentViewController(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
            alertController.addAction(photosLibraryAction)
        }
```

Then I get the images:

```
 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {


            if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
                //Change aspect when not dummy image
                self.bigImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
                self.bigImage.clipsToBounds = true
                self.bigImage.image = pickedImage
```

Comment: `[kUTTypeImage as String]` is actually default for the `mediaTypes` property. It states, that one can only pick still images. If you need to allow videos, set `mediaTypes` to `[kUTTypeMovie as String]`.

Comment: @ovejka Ok so I can use kUTTypeMovie if I want to allow videos. But is there any reason I should implement mediaTypes in my code above? And also post your answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: There is no reason for you. Some people just prefer to be explicit in such decisions. For example, if one doesn't use `UIImagePickerController` directly, but uses a subclass and not sure if this property wasn't overridden. Or if one is afraid, that Apple will change the default in the future framework versions (hardly possible in this particular case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`kUTTypeImage` is actually default for the `mediaTypes` property. It states, that one can only pick still images. If you are ok with this default, you don't need to set it explicitly in your code.

Here is the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/1619173-mediatypes